# How can I get an image of text transcribed where I can specify the font (TFF file)?

Tags: fonts, adobe-photoshop, ocr, transcription

Is there possibly some way to quickly transcribe a large amount of text in a weird font (i.e. something like BulletMix: https://www.fontstock.net/4041/bulletmix.html)? I have access to photoshop, but an online method would be preferred. I have looked online, but I can't quite get the right Google search that doesn't come up with font recognizers (I already know what font the text is in). Any help would be awesome, thanks!

Comment: copy/paste to something that can only handle plain text?

Comment: No, the text is in an image - no copy and pasting.

Comment: Then I've no idea. OCR on a font like the one you linked would need some very specific recognition